# SFML object will only move at a small distance?

Tags: c++, sfml

i am new to SFML and was wandering why my player will only move at a certain distance witch is a very small distance.

Here is my code:
game.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Game!");

    while(window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        sf::Font font;
        if(!font.loadFromFile("../resources/Lets Coffee.ttf"))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        
        sf::Text text("Use the WASD keys to move the player around", font, 20);
        text.setPosition(5, 5);

        // make a player sprite
        sf::Texture *playerTexture;
        playerTexture = new sf::Texture();
        if(!playerTexture->loadFromFile("../resources/Bluey.png"))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        sf::RectangleShape player(sf::Vector2f(128, 128));
        player.setPosition(400, 300);
        player.setTexture(playerTexture);
        player.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
        player.setOutlineThickness(10);

        // Here is my distance problem:
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)) {
            player.move(0, -5);
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)) {
            player.move(0, 5);
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) {
            player.move(-5, 0);
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) {
            player.move(5, 0);
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.draw(player);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could any of you help?, and am i doing something wrong?, if i am the please tell me!

Comment: The issue is that you are creating the player object within your main loop, so each cycle you create a new object and that's why it seems like it's moving a short distance but it's just different objects moving once and then being destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit : **Gerard0097**

> The issue is that your are creating the player object within your main loop, so each cycle you create a new object and that's why is seems like it's moving a short distance but it's just different objects moving once and then being destroyed

Credit : Me

Just create player and texture before main loop (game loop) :

```
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Game!");

  sf::Font font;
  if(!font.loadFromFile("../resources/Lets Coffee.ttf"))
      return EXIT_FAILURE;

  sf::Text text("Use the WASD keys to move the player around", font, 20);
  text.setPosition(5, 5);

  sf::Texture *playerTexture;
  playerTexture = new sf::Texture();
  if(!playerTexture->loadFromFile("../resources/Bluey.png"))
      return EXIT_FAILURE;

   sf::RectangleShape player(sf::Vector2f(128, 128));
   player.setPosition(400, 300);
   player.setTexture(playerTexture);
   player.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
   player.setOutlineThickness(10);
```

and then your game loop :

```
   while (game.isOpen) {
   // Your Game Logic, Event Handling and drawings
   }
```